# How to style responsive table to make table like list?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I have my aspx code here:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SearchCustomer.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.eyeofheaven.SearchCustomer" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="StyleSheets/SearchCustomerStyle.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Search Customer</title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="twelve columns">
            <!-- Header-->
            <div class="container">
                <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
                    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Collection of nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="EyeOfHeaven.aspx">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                                <a data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle active" href="#">Search<b class="caret"></b></a>
                                <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="SearchCustomer.aspx">Search Form(Customer)</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="SearchVehicle.aspx">Search Form(Vehicle)</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Search form customer-->
<div id="searchcustomer" class="page-header">
    <h3><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large"></span>Search Customer</h3>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" runat="server" id="search" size="20" class="form-control" placeholder="Customer ID">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="Country">
            <option value="select" selected disabled>Search by Country</option>
            <option value="A:C ESTUDIO">A:C ESTUDIO</option>
            <option value="Aaron McEwen-194712">Aaron McEwen-194712</option>
        </select>
    </div>  

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="form-control" runat="server" id="Currency">
            <option value="selected" selected disabled>Search by Currency</option>
            <option value="AUD">AUD (Australian Dollar)</option>
            <option value="EUR">EUR (Euro)</option>
            <option value="GBP">GBP (United Kingdom Pounds)</option>
            <option value="JPY">JPY (Japan Yen)</option>
            <option value="NZD">NZD (New Zealand Dollar)</option>
            <option value="USD">USD (United States Dollar)</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button1_Click" id="searchinfo" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span> Search Info</button>
<button type="button" runat="server" onserverclick="Button2_Click" id="Button2" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-repeat"></span>Reset</button>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Information Table-->
<div id="gridview">
    <asp:GridView runat="Server" id="data" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And my css style here:

```
#searchcustomer{
    margin-top:51px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#3399FF;
}
#gridview {
    margin: 20px;
}
#data {
    display: block;
    height:400px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
/* Zebra striping */
    tr:nth-of-type(odd) { 
        background: #eee; 
    }
    th { 
        background: #333; 
        color: white; 
        font-weight: bold; 
    }
    td, th { 
        padding: 6px; 
        border: 1px solid #ccc; 
        text-align: left; 
    }

 @media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    
    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    #data table, 
    #data thead, 
    #data tbody, 
    #data th, 
    #data td, 
    #data tr { 
        display: block; 
    }
 
    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    #data thead tr { 
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }
 
    #data tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }
 
    #data td { 
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee; 
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%; 
        white-space: normal;
        text-align:left;
    }
 
    #data td:before { 
        /* Now like a table header */
        position: absolute;
        /* Top/left values mimic padding */
        top: 6px;
        left: 6px;
        width: 45%; 
        padding-right: 10px; 
        white-space: nowrap;
        text-align:left;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
}
```

The output is okay when viewed on website:
[image]
But when viewed on mobile the output is like this:

[image]

All of my "th" seems to display before my all my "td"
How do I revised my css to make an output not like this. I want to make my table when viewed on mobile (It will get the th and td display)
Example:
When viewed on mobile:
The output is:
(First it will display the th tag "IDCustomer" and next to it is the td which is "253433")
(Image below)

Note:(I just edited this image on paint to further explain my question.)

[image]

How Do I design a css style like this?

Comment: How have to planned to display ?

Comment: Yes sir, I want to display like the last image, in my code when I accessed into mobile. the one I have display all my th and after that displays all my td.(I refer it to image 2)  how do I revised my css code like in the sample (image 3?

Comment: what in case of multiple rows ?

Comment: The table I created is dynamic sir, so when I click the button it will get the data into the database and display it into gridview, what I want for my code is how do I revised my css to display first the IDCustomer which is "th" and next to display is its "td" data which is "253433". I think row 1 is for (IDCustomer) row 2 is for(253433) and so on.

Comment: you can use some jquery plugins or scrollable with only scrollable on the table area.

Comment: <div class="box-body table-responsive"></div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use responsive solution for this :
[solutions here](http://exisweb.net/responsive-table-plugins-and-patterns)

Comment: this does not change my table display sir, my table is generic I did not add any table tags in it, I am only using gridview, when i click the search button it automatically creates th and tds